# Error al crear un atributo con Angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, angular

Quiero crear un atributo que llame a (click) desde setAtributte(), pero me dice este error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 
'(click)' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Busque por todo Google y no estoy encontrando la solucion, se que es por los parentesis pero necesito hacer que angular ejecute una funcion. No quiero tener que crear un atributo onClick para luego tener que crear un archivo Jquery y desde ahi ejecutar el metodo.

Parte del codigo y donde se aplica el error:

```
this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, div);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'type', 'button');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'data-toggle', 'modal');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'data-target', '#modalArbol');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(button, '(click)', 'mostrarId()');
      this.renderer.addClass(button, 'wild');
      this.renderer.addClass(button, 'btn-primary');
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día colega! entiendo el porque dices "crear un archivo Jquery y desde ahi ejecutar el metodo" yo tuve un casi similar dado que la función que añades por medio de addEventlistener se ejecuta en un contexto distinto al de la clase del componente. Pero puedes hacer esto:

```
.addEventListener('click', this.nombreDeFuncionEnComponente.bind(this, [parametros]));
```

Y ya con ello puedes ejecutar una función que esté dentro de la clase del componente en el cual estas trabajando.
Por [parametros] me refiero a esto:

```
// Esta es la función en tu component.ts
nombreDeFuncionEnComponente(nombre:string, edad:number) {}

.addEventListener('click', this.nombreDeFuncionEnComponente.bind(this, 'Sergio', 28));
```

Prueba y me cuentas!